# How do i write a timer countdown in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to write a countdown in C#, but I can't get it to work. I want it to countdown from 1:00 to 0:00. 
How can that be accomplished?

```
public int tidTilbage = 60;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer tidTimer = new Timer();
        tidTimer.Interval = (1000);
        tidTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        tidTimer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tidTilbage = tidTilbage - 1;

        label1.Text.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: How is your current code not working?

Comment: `label1.Text.ToString();` makes no sense, and maybe that's where you want to update the label. Therefore, the line should read: `label1.Text = tidTilbage.ToString()`

Comment: A few things to point out here. This last line in Timer_Tick does absolutely nothing. You also dont need () around your int-literal. I'm guessing that it's a displaying problem right? If you just set the text it'll be 60, 59 etc. If this is not what you want you could use TimeSpan.FromSeconds. With that you get a timespan, which you can then format. [See ms-docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing the

```
 label1.Text.ToString();
```

to

```
  label1.Text = tidTilbage.ToString();
```